# Why the banner showing that the question is closed before it was asked?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, closed-questions, user-experience, banner

I came across two questions and observed their Asked, Active and Closed date-time string. Following is the screen shot of one of it:

[image: Screenshot]

Question Asked  on: 2020-04-16 00:28:14Z
Question Closed on: 2020-04-16 11:41:00Z

As you can see, there is difference in time string while displaying Asked, Active and Closed date time string. Actual difference in time stamp is just few hours; but while displaying date-time string, it is one month.

Comment: See the MSE question [Post was closed before it even existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344532). They use 2 different time relativisers and an employee [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344532/post-was-closed-before-it-even-existed#comment1179084_344532): "Thanks for reporting - agree this is confusing. Adding this to our backlog to address in the future, and when we have more updates, will post here."

Comment: @JeanneDark: Thanks; that is same issue.