# Inconsistent date rounding

Tags: bug, post-notice, timestamps

In some contexts in the site, a date is shown as *"happened x <time units> ago"*. For example on post notices for closing or deleting.

Today I encountered a weird inconsistency in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032925/python-trying-to-open-and-read-file-and-then-close-it-without-exiting-script). At the top of the page it says *"**Asked 5 months ago**"* and on the single deleted answer it says *"**It was deleted 6 months ago**"*.

Obviously it is impossible that the answer was deleted before the question was even asked. I assume this is due to different rounding. The question and answer were posted on February 3rd so we are one week away from it being exactly 6 months.

---

For <10k and a time-freeze:

question's header:

[image]

Deleted answer:

[image]

Comment: Probably related: [Why the banner showing that the question is closed before it was asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401896/11682469)

Comment: indeed and that links to this overmeta post describing the exact same bug but an even worse example of it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344532/post-was-closed-before-it-even-existed

Comment: @Gimby That meta post is tagged status-complete so either it is wrong, or it's a different bug. How can we know if it's the same bug? (I am really asking) Those two links are about the close notice, I saw it on a delete notice of an answer. How can we confirm it is exactly the same? (in such case I will close this as a duplicate)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, but that it's the same underlying issue: Different date formatters are used and so far it was only fixed for the "Closed" but not the "Deleted" date.

Comment: *"That meta post is tagged status-complete so either it is wrong, or it's a different bug."* ... It has that tag __and__ an answer with more information. It explains what the fix was and why your case isn't solved with that fix. And since they were reluctant to do more there, I don't think they will change it for this case.